# Change SQL script to output to own fields instead on one field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below CTE and the CTE query def is the part im having trouble with. What i would like to do is somehow output the CTE query def results to produce one table so that each field (example 'GreaterThan350') is output as a field header and the count is shown as a record.
The script below is not set in stone (IE using a CTE) im open to a solution that works with that result from of the CTE.

Like this:

[image]

Rather than like this:

[image]

```
WITH AgedCircGrouped_CTE(PWNum, NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate, OrderDate, CurrentStage, CircuitID) AS 
(
SELECT 
    cir.[PW Number] AS PWNum
    --Get the correct number of working dayts since the order date by using the fn_WorkDays function
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SharedInfo.dbo.fn_WorkDays(cir.[Install Date], GETDATE()),103) AS NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate 
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ISNULL(cir.[Install Date],'01/01/1900'),103) AS  OrderDate--Get the order dates
    ,ISNULL(cirRep.CurrentStage, 'Not Set') AS CurrentStage
    ,cir.[ID] as CircuitID
    FROM Quotebase.dbo.Circuits cir
        LEFT JOIN Quotebase.dbo.CircuitReports cirRep ON Cir.[PW Number] = CirRep.PWNumber
    WHERE Cir.Status='New Circuit Order' 
    --ORDER BY Cir.[PW Number]
)


SELECT 
    COUNT ([NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] ) AS GreaterThan350
FROM [AgedCircGrouped_CTE]
WHERE [NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] > '350'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COUNT ([NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] ) AS Between250AND350
FROM [AgedCircGrouped_CTE]
WHERE [NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] BETWEEN '250' and '350'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COUNT ([NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] ) AS Between180AND250
FROM [AgedCircGrouped_CTE]
WHERE [NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] BETWEEN '180' and '250'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COUNT ([NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] ) AS Between120AND180
FROM [AgedCircGrouped_CTE]
WHERE [NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] BETWEEN '120' and '180'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COUNT ([NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] ) AS Between70AND120
FROM [AgedCircGrouped_CTE]
WHERE [NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] BETWEEN '70' and '120'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COUNT ([NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] ) AS Between40AND70
FROM [AgedCircGrouped_CTE]
WHERE [NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] BETWEEN '40' and '70'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COUNT ([NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] ) AS LessThan40
FROM [AgedCircGrouped_CTE]
WHERE [NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate] < '40'

GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest method:

```
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate < '40' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As LessThan40
     , Sum(CASE WHEN NumberOfDaysSinceOrderDate BETWEEN '40' AND '70' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Between40AND70
     , etc...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solution is perfect for my needs.